# what should be the min number of samples and sampling frequency while playing sound

Tags: image-processing

As i am using open Al library for generating a tune. I was able to generate a tone for single frequency.

When I was trying to generate tone for multiple frequncies, it suffered from the problem of clipping and noise. So please sugest me how to rectify the problem.

Comment: If you have two tones both with amplitude of 1 (for now the limit) the sum of those two tones will be above the limit of the signal. in tha t case you get clipping for free. So check if the sum of all your tones is not above the limit!!

Answer (score 1):

Your sampling frequency should be at least two times higher than the highest frequency in your signal. (Read about [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)).
This has nothing to do with clipping.
I can imagine that your clipping occurs because you are adding multiple signals without scaling (normalizing) the amplitudes.